# Библиотека chrono

Tags: c++, qt

Есть 2 кнопки. При нажатии первой, записалось время нажатия, потом через какое-то время нажимаю вторую кнопку, и уже разница между нажатиями этих кнопок выводится в label на экран.

**1 кнопка**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<float> duration = end - start;
    ui->lbl4->setText(QString::number(duration.count()));
}
```

**2 кнопка**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    QFile out("text.txt");
    if (out.open(QIODevice::Append)){
        QTextStream stream(&out);
        stream << ui->lineEdit->text() << "\n";
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Да, я понимаю что ошибка в том, что я объявляю переменные в кнопках. В этом и вопрос, как правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Например, через переменные-члены в `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука в `Qt` как класс `QObject`, а в нем есть метод `setProperty`. Вы можете воспользоваться этим методом в своим коварных целях, например:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    ui->lbl4->setProperty("start", start.time_since_epoch().count()); // Сохраняем отсечку времени
    //...
}
```

Далее

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    qlonglong start = ui->label->property("start").toLongLong();
    qlonglong end = high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    duration<qlonglong> duration(end - start);
    ui->lbl4->setText(QString::number(duration.count()));
}
```

Comment: [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/151gfbw)

Comment: @Mkorny там QVariant, поэтому надо в миллисекунды перевести

Comment: Точнее в понятный QVariant формат, в частности миллисекунды

Comment: Никогда с этим не работал, поэтому не понимаю о чем вы..

Comment: @Mkorny как же вы работаете с фреймворком и даже в документацию не заглядываете? Вы же себе тем самым сильно усложняете жизнь. Ответ, кстати, подправил, проверяйте

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно реализовать секундомер через эту библиотеку. Так же, ```duration``` в вашем коде никак не считает разность между ```end``` и ```start```, а выдает то же значение, что и у ```end```. Так же в документацию я заглядывал, но не нашел того, что мне нужно, возможно плохо искал, не отрицаю.